# How Python Pandas can read C++ struct binary from command line

Tags: python, c++

I have a `std::vector` of a custom struct called `SomeData`:

```
struct SomeData
{
    float a;
    bool b;
    int c;
};
```

I write this data to file in binary by `reinterpet_cast`-ing the object to bytes:

```
myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const SomeData*>(&obj), sizeof(obj));
```

A Python user wants to load this data in to Pandas from the Linux command line. However, obviously Pandas doesn't know what the `SomeData` struct looks like.

Is there any way the Python user can read the binary file in to Pandas? Could PyBind help here- a wrapper or something?

```
pandasTable = wrapperToConvertSomeDataToPandas()
```

(I'd really prefer to avoid using Parquet)

Comment: There are lots of ways to read data in python, depends what the data is, please provide a [mre]

Comment: How do you write this data in binary, what serialization method do yo use? PyBind "could" help of course, there are multiple possibilities to solve it. For now I think your question is not easily answerable.

Comment: @pptaszni Hi, i've just updated my question. I reinterpret the C++ object to bytes. Happy to modify the question to help make it easier to answer.

Comment: What fields does `SomeData` contain? If it contains pointers or C++ objects, your bytes representation is meaningless out of your C++ program.

Comment: @Botje No pointers or strings, assume just float, bool and ints

Comment: BTW, you have a typo: it should be `<const char*>`, not `<const SomeData*>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you switch to a serialization format that is self-describing, such as AVRO. That puts the burden only on the C++ program; your Python code just receives a list of objects. It may seem heavy-handed now, but it will save you time and pain later on.

Comment: I just responded to your comment question. Is your answer the same knowing it's just primitive types?

Comment: Yes. Serialization is a solved problem, you should use AVRO (or any other common serialization library like protobufs or Thrift or even JSON) and spend your time on your actual business problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some serialization library (e.g. [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)), as already suggested in the previous answer. However, if you really wish to stay with your `reinterpret_cast` solution, you can write a python function that knows your `SomeData` structure, interprets the binary file correctly and returns Pandas DataFrame. For example:

```
import struct
import pandas as pd

def readBinaryData(myFile):
    d = {'float': [], 'bool': [], 'int': []}
    buff = myFile.read(12)
    while (len(buff) == 12):
        d['float'].append(struct.unpack("f", buff[0:4])[0])
        d['bool'].append(bool(struct.unpack("i", buff[4:8])[0]))
        d['int'].append(struct.unpack("i", buff[8:12])[0])
        buff = myFile.read(12)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = readBinaryData(open("output.bin", "rb"))
print(df)
```

Possible output:

```
   float   bool  int
0    1.1   True    1
1    2.2  False    2
2    3.3  False    3
```

The problem with this approach is that you need to know the size of your C++ datatypes, which might be implementation-dependent. In my case the size of `SomeData` struct was 12, instead of expected 4 + 1 + 4 = 9 bytes. For that reason `bool(struct.unpack("i", buff[4:8])[0])`, because of structure padding.

Then according to your client's requirements, you can distribute it as source or a python package, or some shared library.